# Nodejs many http request callback

Tags: node.js

I have to request to multi http request, and wait all callback to update result.
I 'm using jxcore to make it workby multi thread, and by multi pc.
Any idea how to improve it ? 
I'm using async.each to execute 5000 url each task. 
I have about 100000 urls to request , and it wasted about 3h to finish (on 1 pc)

Comment: What's the response time for just one request?

Comment: it's actualy a request to get windowsphone push notification, my network is slow now, so it's about 5-10s

Comment: I think this is an IO bottleneck - a parallelism of 5000 can do nothing about this. Try some smaller parallelism degrees (like a few dozens) on a sample of the URLs

Comment: I used async.each, so I think it will handle it this limit for me.